# What's the difference in the way these two event listener callbacks are added? Function VS arrow function calling the function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

1. What are the resulting effects one needs to be aware of with each of the approaches bellow?
2. Is the arrow-function approach better if I needed to call a function whilst passing it an argument which isn't the triggering event itself?

```
document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', () => myFunction1(param1));
document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', myFunction2);
```

Comment: "*Is the arrow-function approach better if I needed to call a function whilst passing it an argument*" - there's no "better". The second line simply doesn't work if you want to pass your own argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the function inline, like with

```
() => myFunction1(param1)
```

will

- call `myFunction1` without a `this` of the element (if you're on the top level, `this` inside the function will be either the window object or `undefined`)
- call `myFunction` with a parameter of `param1` instead of a parameter of the click event

The second approach is sometimes used as shorthand when you want to refer to the element the listener was attached to inside the listener, eg:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  this.remove();
}
document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', myFunction2);
```

```html
<button id="element">click</button>
```

To do the same sort of thing in the first approach, you'd either have to save the `#element` in a variable first, or select it again with `querySelector`.

> Is the arrow-function approach better if I needed to call a function whilst passing it an argument which isn't the triggering event itself?

Yes, that's a very common way of doing it.

Another way is to make a higher-order function, like so:

```js
const makeMyFunction1 = (param) => () => console.log(param);
document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', makeMyFunction1('foo'));
```

```html
<button id="element">click</button>
```

Also keep in mind that if you want to be able to remove a listener later, you *must* use a named function:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  console.log('hi');
  this.removeEventListener('click', myFunction2);
}
document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', myFunction2);
```

```html
<button id="element">click</button>
```

Comment: Even if tangential there should probably be a note about how anonymous functions can't be removed with removeEventListener.